# ssh not using the config file in home directory

Tags: ssh, aws-codecommit

Using:

- OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
- OSX: 10.10.5

I am following the [AWS CodeCommit setup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html#setting-up-ssh-unixes-account).

My config file looks like:

```
HostName git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  User <myuserid that is supplied from aws is here>
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

But it is not accessing that local config file. It keeps looking for id_rsa and I get *Permission denied (publickey)*. The only way I can ssh is to this is to manually run:

```
ssh -i codecommit_rsa <myuserid from amazon>@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

from ssh -v :

```
CLI-24420:.ssh nsturgess$ ssh -v git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [54.239.20.155] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version AWSCodeCommit VHVlLCAxMiBKYW4gMjAxNiAyMTo1NjowMCArMDAwMOVgljlXewI0PWsqvMExhuwd1npoXpT8tFGX2PJoBfPLVW
debug1: no match: AWSCodeCommit VHVlLCAxMiBKYW4gMjAxNiAyMTo1NjowMCArMDAwMOVgljlXewI0PWsqvMExhuwd1npoXpT8tFGX2PJoBfPLVWh2dkRHbCtza1J3WWNXVWNVU2llek9SZ0MvU24yS1lLdGQxTUFGOTNOeEU9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a6:9c:7d:bc:35:f5:d4:5f:8b:ba:6f:c8:bc:d4:83:84
debug1: Host 'git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: codecommit_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nsturgess/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can someone allude to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: where exactly do  you have your config stored? What are permissions on the config file? Post verbose log from `ssh -vvv ...`.

Comment: config is in ~/.ssh and it had been chmod'ed with 600

Comment: I asked for `-vvv` for more verbose log. There might be still something more hidden. Something is preventing reading the file. What are the permissions of the directory `~/.ssh/` itself?

Comment: Does it work to manually specify the config file? `ssh -F ~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 1):

Solution was that for some reason the config file when created was for *root*, so after changing the ownership it worked!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please explain how did you change the ownership?